# winui3/uwp Is there anyway to force updating GUI during the code excute in UI thread

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, winui-3

I want to progammly select a new created item in treeview (windowscommunitytoolkit), however, the TreeViewItem/TreeViewNode of that item will not been built till the GUI update, also will not been built till the rootnode expand (if the rootnode is in collapsed state, but itemsource change).

The tree structure is:

```
rootnode
--node1
----subnode1
----subnode2
--node2
```

If I do something like that

```
rootnodeitem.NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemSouceBindData");      // It will update rootnode children.
treeview.Expand(rootnode);      // Try to make rootnode expand to make new TreeViewItem load
foreach(var node in rootnode.Children) treeview.Expand(node);
treeview.SelectedNode = treeview.NodefromContainer(treeview.ContainerfromItem(subnode1item));
```

Line3 and line4 are all useless, for after the `treeview.Expand(rootnode);`, node1.Children.Count=0, So `treeview.Expand(node)` will do nothing and `treeview.ContainerfromItem(subnode1item)` or `treeview.NodefromContainer(...)` will all return null.

So I wonder if I can do something like that

```
rootnodeitem.NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemSouceBindData");      // It will update rootnode children.
FoceRefreshGUI();
treeview.Expand(rootnode);      // Try to make rootnode expand to make new TreeViewItem load
FoceRefreshGUI();
foreach(var node in rootnode.Children) treeview.Expand(node);
FoceRefreshGUI();
treeview.SelectedNode = treeview.NodefromContainer(treeview.ContainerfromItem(subnode1item));
```

I try lots of things like use `await Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(10000); });`, but it is hard to control the delay time and also it will not gurantee the GUI finish update during the delay time.

So I wonder is there anyway to force updating GUI during the code excute in UI thread?
Or Is there anyway to force treeview refresh to build all its new chilnodes?

Thank you very much if you have any idea

Updated the binding xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="grouptemplate_"
                      x:DataType="local:ModelLeafItem">
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemSouceBindData, Mode=OneWay}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Width="10"
                           Source="{x:Bind ImageSrc}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="itemtemplate_"
                      x:DataType="local:ModelLeafItem">
            <TreeViewItem>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border Background="{x:Bind IconBrush}">
                        <Image Width="10"
                               Source="{x:Bind ImageSrc}" />
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:ModelItemTemplateSelector x:Key="modelitemtemplateselector_"
                                         GroupTemplate="{StaticResource grouptemplate_}"
                                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemtemplate_}" />
    </Page.Resources>
<Grid>
        <TreeView x:Name="treeview_"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ModelData, Mode=OneWay}"
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource modelitemtemplateselector_}"
                  SelectionMode="Single">
        </TreeView>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Doesn't this thing use an observable collection?

Comment: @aybe The "ItemSouceBindData" is a observable collection. But my problem is that the UI (treeview) only update after the function finish, So I can't expand or select some node inside the function.

Comment: You mean you want to select (or expand) an item right after you added to the "itemsSourceBindData"?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, or when reset the "itemsSourceBindData"

Comment: Is "itemsSourceBindData" bound to the ``TreeView``? or you are passing it from code-behind? Can you share code around that?

Comment: @Andrew Ofcourse ok, it is x:bind to the TreeViewItem' ItemSource. I have updated the xaml in the question body.

Comment: @all After a long time test, I found found this problem which I cannot programmly select/expand may not caused by UI not updating immediately, but a known bug [link](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7044)

Comment: I'm not sure if your problem is related to the issue in the repo. You can select and item by setting the ``SelectedItem`` and expand an item by binding the IsExpanded property. To expand a deep item you need to expand its higher items manually though.